# AWS API Gateway Http proxy to call external API with Authentication

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

In AWS API Gateway I need to create a proxy for a existing external API. I know this can be achieved using Http Proxy Integration type easily.

But on top of this I have a requirement to call another external API for authentication and retrieve the auth token first and then use that token to call the external main API.

Is there any simple pattern available for this which can be configured in the API Gateway?

Possibly Lambda is an option and to put both API call inside that.
But this could add complexity in needs more coding as we have 100s of API. Is there simple configuration available?

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway does not support authentication without using Lambda. You will need to use a Lambda function to authenticate requests before they reach your API.